# How should I create & pass user tokens?

Tags: ios, api, rest, web-applications, flask

I'm writing a web app (in flask) that has an API back end that the iOS app will communicate with. What is the best way to create, pass, and authenticate user tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [flask-oauthprovider](https://github.com/ib-lundgren/flask-oauthprovider). It lets you secure views like this:

```
@provider.require_oauth()
def view_profile():
    ...
```

and handles token requests for you.

Comment: It's documentation seems a bit lacking

Comment: Actually, the code is [pretty well documented](https://github.com/ib-lundgren/flask-oauthprovider/blob/master/flask_oauthprovider.py) -- and at any rate, it's just 350 loc, half of it comments. You'll be an oauthprovider-pro in 30min :)